# Does anyone know how to edit msbuild targets files in Notepad++ with intellisense?

Tags: windows, notepad++, visual-studio

I often edit my msbuild files with Notepad++.However, I miss the intellisense I get when I do so in Visual Studio. Does anyone know how to have the same experience in Notepad++?

Comment: Try using a free utility called MSBuild Explorer.

Comment: Link to MSBuild Explorer: http://www.msbuildexplorer.com/

Comment: Mark, this is a fantastic question.  I just had the same thought.  If only some innovative C programmer could write a plugin that enables intellisense in Notepad++ using only an xsd.  Unfortunately, I don't know C++.

Comment: Alas, even if one knows C++ doing it is still not an option, since few of us are owners of their time.

Answer (score 2):

The Notepad++ auto-completion feature is powered by a bunch of XML files that are located in the `<Notepad++ install dir>\plugins\APIs` folder.  You can create your own language and auto-complete for that language using the tutorials on the website:

- [User-language define system](http://npp-community.tuxfamily.org/documentation/notepad-user-manual/languages/user-defined-languages)
- [Auto-complete](http://sourceforge.net/apps/mediawiki/notepad-plus/index.php?title=Auto_Completion)

Comment: Thanks. But is there a way to make it use the xsd file? I suppose there is an xsd file for the msbuild project files.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the .xsd file from one of these locations depending on if you have Visual studio installed.

\Microsoft Visual Studio 10.0\Xml\Schemas\1033\MSBuild\Microsoft.Build.CommonTypes.xsd

Otherwise look for the XML and XSD file located in the .net version system folder you are using.

c:\windows\microsoft.net\framework\v-----

By the way , to edit and get intelisense in Visual Studio you can do the following:

Open up Visual Studio and go to the Tools -> Options and go to the Text Editor options then you can associate file extensions to text editors. For MSBuild files we need to associate things like “proj” to “XML Editor with Encoding”. Now we also have intellisense to help write the script.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Now all I need is make notepad++ use the XSD files.

Answer (score 1):

I also have the same problem and finally found the better option is to use Visual code. The steps are:

- Install the [MSBuild project
  tools|vscode:extension/tintoy.msbuild-project-tools] in the VS code
- The .msbuild extension is not initially tied up with editor (Only
  .proj, .targets, .props, .tasks are supported by default)
- Change the language mode (Ctrl+Shift+P) to configure file association
- Choose your desired language as MSBuild and you are done.

The details can also be found from [Visual Studio Market Place](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=tintoy.msbuild-project-tools)

Comment: Explain with more detail than just a link. If the link dies, then how helpful will this answer be... think about that and edit accordingly.